# magento 2 move product_list_toolbar after category.cms or category.view.container

Tags: magento2, layout, catalog, toolbar

I like to move the product_list_toolbar element after the category.cms or category.view.container, for that have tried the following code

```
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="category.view.container" after="-"/>
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="category.cms" after="-" />
```

But nothing seems to work, it's throwing the Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getSize() on null.

for your further reference herewith I have attached my expected things.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add below code in `catalog_category_view.xml` file in your custom theme:-

```
<move element="product_list_toolbar" destination="columns.top" after="page.main.title" />
```